# .htaccess rewriterule to create subdomains

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, subdomain

I want to create subdomains, so that I can use the address test.mydomain.com.

After searching the web, and a lot of trial, I got this in my .htacces file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+)\.mydomain\.com(:80)?$
    RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/subdomains/%1/$1 -f [OR]
    RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/subdomains/%1/$1 -d
    RewriteRule (.*) /subdomains/%1/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

If I write http: //test.mydomain.com/folder/ in my browser everything is fine.

But if I write http: //test.mydomain.com/folder *(without ending slash)*, it gets redirected to http: //test.mydomain.dk/subdomains/test/folder/, and this is the address shown in the browser (which I don't want)

My question is:
How do I prevent the redirect?
I want to only see http: //test.mydomain.com/folder in the browser. Regardless of the ending slash.

My web files is like this:

```
.htaccess
index.php (page for mydomain.com)
\subdomains
    \test
        \hello
         index.php (page for test.mydomain.com/hello)
```

Thanks.

*(sorry about the spaces in the url's. It won't let my post with links)*

Comment: see [`DirectorySlash`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_dir.html#directoryslash)

Comment: didn't work: try this: http://app.npham.dk/test/ vs. http://app.npham.dk/test

Comment: 1) I can't see any external redirects in rules so the reason may be not in rules. `DirectorySlash On` (it is default value) can make redirect. 2) I'm not sure about AND/OR priority in `RewriteCond`s so `[OR]` flag can break your conditions. 3) `$1` back-references can only be used in `RewriteRule` so remove it from `RewriteCond` and use `%{REQUEST_URI}`.

Answer (score 0):

got it to work now:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine on

    # If requested URI does not end in "/"
    RewriteCond $1 !/$
    # add a trailing slash
    RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /$1/ [R=301,L]

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+)\.mydomain\.com(:80)?$
    RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/subdomains/%1/%{REQUEST_URI} -d [OR]
    RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/subdomains/%1/%{REQUEST_URI} -f
    RewriteRule (.*) /subdomains/%1/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```